# Adobe Creative Suite CS5 - One License Multiple Macs

Tags: install, software, adobe-photoshop, license

As freelance web designer I have a total of four macs. I have an office I use during the day with an iMac and MacBook for taking to client meetings. And I also have a iMac and MacBook at home for generally personal use.

I have bought licenses for Coda, Postbox and a few other programs that I use and they work across all four macs but I would like to do the same with Adobe Creative Suite CS5.

I know the simple answer is buy more than one license but at the price they are that would be very expensive. I understand that using it on more than computer may break terms of the EULA? My question is will it even activate on more than one computer or is this impossible?

Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adobe's answer](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/faq.html) will be:

> **Q**: Can I distribute a Creative Suite 5.5 edition across multiple
>   users or computers?
>
> **A**:The software license agreement accompanying your product may
>   entitle you to install and activate the software on two systems with
>   certain restrictions.  The product license agreement for suite
>   editions does not allow you to install the individual components of a
>   single suite edition across multiple computers. Read the software
>   license agreement for more information. Subscription editions follow
>   the same license agreement terms.

With that in mind you will need two licenses for the products you use, you may not need the entire creative suite on each computer and find it cheaper to purchase licenses for individual apps.

If you buy apps from the Apple App Store you can install those apps on any computer that you use the same Apple ID with. Adobe has yet to move their apps to the App Store, but I suspect they will at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate CS on 2 different computers. You can however install it on more than 2 computers and (de)activate on an as-needed basis, given that only 2 installations are activated at any given time. To deactivate, go to the Help menu of one of the CS applications.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you email Adobe and ask them to give you an additional license key, explaining your situation.  I've heard of other software vendors doing similar things such as [Ableton](http://www.ableton.com/)